# Time required to open very small to very large leveldb databases

Tags: c++, leveldb

I have to give some background first. I want to implement an optimized storage engine for OSM planet data (50GB+). The purpose of this engine is to enable map area extractions as fast as possible - while also remaining the ability for minutely updates. The design I've chosen for several reasons (not mentioning all of them here) is to use one data cell per grid. E.g. think of a all cells on a map being distinct files or databases: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_CntRFtGsdQo/TTU5UMlLkTI/AAAAAAAAARk/_hW8n33t4Ok/s1600/utmworld.gif

(Jut to get the idea though, this is not the actual cell grid I'll be using)

I have never used leveldb before, but settled on it for it's bulk insert and update performance. However, I'd like to know about the "performance characteristics" when opening many very small and very large leveldb databases. very small meaning just a few kB, very large meaning a few hundred MB

I expect that I have to open / close somewhere between 10-100 dbs per minute. I'd rule out leveldb if it needs significant initialization time.

An answer to this question could be either concrete figures, or insight to what leveldb does during initialization and how it relates to data / index size.

PS. I'll also do my own measurements of course. But as with all tests, I may draw wrong conclusions from my sample data.